# Problemas con el compilador Mingw-w64 - (CMD)

Tags: c++, vscode

Mi problema es que al abrir cmd escribo : g++ --versión y en ves de aparecerme la información en la misma ventana me abre otra y se cierra en negro. Eso pasó porque yo viendo por curiosidad entre en la carpeta

> C:\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin

de mi instalación, y abrí los ejecutable como es el:

> gcc.exe
>
> g++.exe

Para ver que hacían. Pero después de eso no me funcionaba C++ en VSCode, Error en includePath y todo lo demás, SOLAMENTE POR ESE ERROR!, Espero sus respuestas y Gracias...!

Answer (score -1):

Hace unos meses a mi laptop le pasó mismo , ahora a mi PC con el compialdor mingw32, pero fíjate estaba limpiando unos archivos y cambie el nombre de la carpeta principal sin eliminarla del Path antes. Luego fui al al path y ajuste el nombre y Boom me pasa ese error y me he metido en cuanto foto en inglés y en español y nada.

Hace tiempo estaba aprendiendo ensamblador con un libro de Randall hyde y el tiene una página donde tiene un ensamblador para si lenguaje y cuando lo descargue sin ajustarlo al path me daba el mismo error pero eso fue en mi laptop me da la sospecha que es por ese archivo corrupto que me hizo algo en path porque hice lo mismo con mi PC y ahora me da ese error.

1. puede ser ese archivo que daño algo en path o
2. cuando hice el ajuste  dañe algún archivo en el path que el compilador necesita para andar bien. Saludos si ya resolviste por favor avísame

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en españo. por favor no utilices el área de respuesta para realizar un comentario, revisa [answer], si quieres respuesta a un problema especifico puedes publicar tu pregunta([ask]), también puedes realizar el [tour] para conocer como funciona la pagina.